# Unable to run Groovy Script in Anypoint Studio (7.4.2) by calling using gmaven pom plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy, mule

I wanted to use groovy for the maven build of my mule project. So, I went ahead started using the `gmaven plugin` as given below in the pom.xml, and I also added the `test.groovy` under /src/main/resources.

Contents of the `test.groovy`

```
   println "Hello, world Maven with Groovy***********************************************!"
   println "Entry****"
   println "Exit****"
```

Plugin in the `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                   <id>call-groovy</id>
                   <!-- <phase>prepare-package</phase> -->
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>execute</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>src/main/resources/test.groovy</source>
                   </configuration>
                </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
                <source>src/main/resources/test.groovy</source>
                <!-- This to call the source without using execution id in mvn command-->
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run any of the below mvn command from the root folder of the project, the script is successfully getting executed and displaying the message in the command prompt.

> **mvn org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:execute**

> **mvn org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:execute@call-groovy**

> **mvn clean package**

[image]

But when I run the same project in **Anypoint studio**, which is an eclipse based integration tool, I get the below error. I already checked the `windows > preferences > maven`, and tried to run using all the above maven commands as a part of the program.

I want to know why this error is happening or what am I doing wrong? HELP!!!

---

### ERROR as below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sys-kitty 1.0.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean-1) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Heisenberg\sys-kitty\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:clean (default-clean) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:validate (default-validate) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:initialize (default-initialize) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:process-sources (default-process-sources) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] About to fetch required dependencies for artifact: 9f62fda4-113d-407f-96eb-ef93fb78a31d:sys-kitty:pom:1.0.5-SNAPSHOT. This may take a while...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:process-resources (default-process-resources) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:compile (default-compile) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (call-groovy) @ sys-kitty ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.556 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-11T18:21:45+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 273M/872M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (call-groovy) on project sys-kitty: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: src for class: script1623415903180 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine with Studio 7.9.0, the current last release of Anypoint Studio. You should download the last version and try.

I recommend to upgrade the plugin to the last release because the one mentioned is very old.

Example:

```
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
```

Comment: Cool. I will try and confirm. Thanks Aled!